# How to separate XML tags in freemarker in body function

Tags: xpath, freemarker

I am trying to write a freemarker function to parse xml but i want to avoid the specific XPATH set from the xml.

The below freemarker is working if the xml does not have DOCUMENT_SETS . But my xml comes with DOCUMENT_SETS and i could not avoid those tags  when i am calling body["MESSAGE//DEALS"]. My list is empty when xml have DOCUMENT_SETS tag in the below xml.

```
<#assign DEALS = body["MESSAGE//DEALS"]>
{
loans:[
 <#list DEALS as d>
    {
        Address1 : ${d[".//AddressLineText"]}
    }
 </#list>       
    ]
}
```

Sample xml

```
<MESSAGE >
 <DEALS>
    <DEAL>
        <AddressLineText>Addr1</AddressLineText>
    </DEAL>
    <DEAL>
        <AddressLineText>Addr2</AddressLineText>
    </DEAL>
  </DEALS>
  <DOCUMENT_SETS>
    <DEALS>
        <DEAL>
            <LateChargeAmount>110</LateChargeAmount>
        </DEAL>
    </DEALS>
 </DOCUMENT_SETS>
 </MESSAGE>
```

How i can get DEAL only under MESSAGE//DEALS , i totally want to avoid DOCUMENT_SETS tag.

Expected output

```
{
 "loans": [
  {
  AddressLineText : Addr1
  },
  {
   AddressLineText : Addr2
  }
  ]
  }
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear: can you edit it and show your exact expected output?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , I added the expected output. All i was trying to do is get the DEAL from MESSAGE and avoid DEAL under DOCUMENT_SETS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your template to

```
<#assign DEALS = someXML["MESSAGE//DEALS[following-sibling::DOCUMENT_SETS]/DEAL"]>
    {
    loans:[
     <#list DEALS as d>
        {
             ${d["name(./*)"]} : ${d["./AddressLineText"]}
             # or ${d["name(./*)"]} : ${d["./*"]}
        }
     </#list>       
        ]
    }
```

The output I get, based on your sample xml is:

```
{
loans:[
    {
         AddressLineText : Addr1
    }
    {
         AddressLineText : Addr2
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i am getting error saying "InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> someXML [in template "VKP.json.ftl" at line 1, column 18] "

Comment: <#assign DEALS = someXML["MESSAGE//DEALS[following-sibling::DOCUMENT_SETS]/DEAL"]>
    {
    loans:[
     <#list DEALS as d>
        {
            ${d["name(./*)"]} : ${d["./*"]}
             
        }
     </#list>       
        ]
    }

Comment: I tried the same xml in the question

Comment: @kp I tried it exactly as in the answer in this sandbox and it works fine: https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Comment: OK , I see it working here . Let me take a look at my implementation. Thanks.